# Nav-bar won't stay in a horizontal line at the top of the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know there are plenty of questions already on similar topics but I've tried inline-block and various bootstrap navbar classes in order to get my buttons in my navbar to stay in a horizontal line.

```
<header class= "navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class= "container navbar-header">
  <div> <%= link_to "ZBLOG", "#", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-left", id: "logo" %></div>
  <ul class= "">
    <li><%= link_to "Home", "#", class: "btn-lg btn-primary navbutton" %>></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Articles", "#", class: "btn-lg btn-primary navbutton" %>></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Contact Me", "#", class: "btn-lg btn-primary navbutton" %>></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Button", "#", class: "btn-lg btn-primary navbutton" %>></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It looks like this should simply have these buttons at the top in a line like you would expect. Instead they are stair stepping down for some reason like this [image: Buttons]. Anyway, any help would be awesome. Thanks guys.

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top;` to the element which has `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @Zach94 - Where is your `</header>`?

Answer (score 0):

Tried this..??

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li>
                <p class="navbar-btn">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">I'm a link button!</a>
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" type="button">I'm a form button!</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps....